# Is there a way to darken the blacks on an image using PHP and the GD library?

Tags: php, gd

I want to punch the blacks (make the blacks and near blacks darker) in an image using PHP and the GD library but I'm not quite sure which methods in the GD library I should use to accomplish this.  My goal is to basically create the same functionality that Photoshop has when doing the following:

1. Open an image in PS
2. Go to Image -> Adjustments -> Selective Color
3. Choose Blacks from the dropdown
4. Choose Relative or Absolute algorithms
5. Drag the Black slider to the right to increase, darken, or punch the blacks.

Comment: You won't be able to make black (0/0/0) any darker, only the near blacks. I think in pure GD, the only way is to scan every pixel individually, compute the new colour, and set it again. If you want a more convenient method, ImageMagick might have something

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with ImageMagic to give similar Absolute effect .. not sure about Relative

```
 convert a.png -level 20%,95%,0.8 al.png
```

[image][image]